# Better solution for Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy

So I have 2 columns and I would like to create a 3rd column based on the values of the second column. I want to start with a text and a number lets say B0292, and if the second value of the column remains the same, my number in the new column will remain the same. If the number changes, then my number will go one up. Like B0293.

```
d = {'col1': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j' ], 'col2': ['200', '200', '201', '201', '201', '201', '210', '210', '250', '251']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

the table:

```
    col1    col2
0   a   200
1   b   200
2   c   201
3   d   201
4   e   201
5   f   201
6   g   210
7   h   210
8   i   250
9   j   251
```

The result i want:

```
col1    col2    New Calculated Column
0   a   200 B0292 - 200
1   b   200 B0292 - 200
2   c   201 B0293 - 201
3   d   201 B0293 - 201
4   e   201 B0293 - 201
5   f   201 B0293 - 201
6   g   210 B0294 - 210
7   h   210 B0294 - 210
8   i   250 B0295 - 250
9   j   251 B0296 - 251
```

I have solved this with the below code, but i am wondering if there is a better more pandas/numpy solution.

```
df['New Calculated Column'] = ''
a = 291
b = 0
for number in df.col2:
    if number != df.iloc[b-1,1]:
        a += 1    
    df['New Calculated Column'].iloc[(b)] = 'B0' + str(a) + ' - ' + df.iloc[b,1]
    if b < 9:
        b += 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your string has numbers starting from the 2nd position , You can try `series.factorize` with string slicing and addition of series:

```
s = "B0292"
s1 = s[0] + pd.Series(int(s[1:]) + df['col2'].factorize()[0],dtype=str)
df['New'] = df['col2'].radd(s1+'-')
```

---

```
print(df)

  ccol1 col2       New
0    a  200  B292-200
1    b  200  B292-200
2    c  201  B293-201
3    d  201  B293-201
4    e  201  B293-201
5    f  201  B293-201
6    g  210  B294-210
7    h  210  B294-210
8    i  250  B295-250
9    j  251  B296-251
```

Comment: Yeap. That's  a better solution. Thank you

Comment: I am getting this error in my real data and i cant find out why. 'TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str'  df.dtypes  shows the column as an object, So everything is str

Comment: There are no nan values. i tried with fillna and with .apply(str) to the df.col2

Comment: @Mike did you try `df['New'] = df['col2'].fillna('').radd(s1+'-')` ?

Comment: @Mike interesting , cant say much without debugging the data safest option: `df['New'] = df['col2'].fillna('').astype(str).radd(s1+'-')` .. try this once maybe

Comment: I did try it and it gave the same error. If I export the data to a CSV and re-import it back, it works. I  can't understand why

Comment: if i add this. `df.to_csv('a') 
df = pd.read_csv('a')` it works

Comment: So an update. The df I was using was a sub df from another df, and the indexes was messed up. when I reset the index using `.reset_index(drop=True)`, the code @anky provided worked. So the problem was the index for some reason.